# More elegant way to write a function composition procedure?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to solve the following problem:

> `my_function_composition(f,g)`
>
> input: two functions f and g, represented as dictionaries, such that g ◦ f exists.
>
> output: dictionary that represents the function g ◦ f.
>
> example: given f = {0:’a’, 1:’b’} and g = {’a’:’apple’, ’b’:’banana’}, return {0:’apple’, 1:’banana’}.

---

I have found a solution, but it feels pretty messy to me:

```
def my_function_composition(f,g): return {list(f.keys())[i]: list(g.values())[i] for i in f if list(f.values()) == list(g.keys())}

# example/test
w = {0:'a', 1:'b', 2: 'c'}
v = {'a': 'apple', 'b':'banana', 'c': 'carrot'}

my_function_composition(w,v)
```

According to the book, the next section includes loop problems, thus I assume there's an elegant one-line solution to this one.

*Note: I would highly appreciate if you could provide comments to your solution, because I'm new with python*

Comment: What'd happen if you had `w = {0: 'a', 1: 'a'}` or anything else similar? It's hard to see what the point of this exercise is with `dict`s effectively being unordered etc... Does the book explain it in the next section as you hint it might? Probably better having a peek at that than someone trying to explain whatever it is the book's trying to point out and confusing matters?

Comment: @Jon Clements it's a math book. According to the theory it's impossible to have a function composition with `w = {0: 'a', 1: 'a'}`.

Comment: Not impossible per se - just loss of data and doesn't make sense... not quite sure where *function composition* comes into this when the examples are updating `dict`s :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
return {fk:g[fv] for fk, fv in f.items() if fv in g}
```

`fk` is a key in `f` and `fv` is the value of the key in `f`.

All I do is create a dictionary where the keys are made up of the keys of `f` and the values are made up of looking up the values of `f` in `g` (if they exist).

*Just to be pedantic, I added the `if fv in g`, which I don't think is a requirement of this exercise.*

Example:

```
>>> def fcomp(f, g): return {fk:g[fv] for fk, fv in f.items() if fv in g}
... 
>>> fcomp({0:'a', 1:'b', 2: 'c'}, {'a': 'apple', 'b':'banana', 'c': 'carrot'})
{0: 'apple', 1: 'banana', 2: 'carrot'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
d = {k: g[v] for k, v in f.items()}
```

`d` becomes:

```
{0: 'apple', 1: 'banana'}
```

Comment: This will throw an error if `g(v)` is not found. You would rather use `g.get(v)` which returns `None` in case the key is missing